# Let $a, u$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $|u| = 1$. Show that there is exactly one number $t$ such that $a - tu$ is orthogonal to $u$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $a, u$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $|u| = 1$. Show that there is exactly one number $t$ such that $a - tu$ is orthogonal to $u$.

**My attempt:**

I tried expanding $(a - tu) \cdot u$ to no avail. The identity $|a-tu||u|\cos\theta  = |a-tu|\cos\theta = 0$ also seems pretty useless. Could someone please give me a **conceptual hint**? I'm very bad with manipulating the dot product.  (That's why I'm doing exercises to improve my fluency in the subject.)

Comment: We have $0=(\vec a-t\vec u)\cdot \vec u=\vec a\cdot \vec u - t \vec u\cdot \vec u$; solve for $t$; do you see where $|\vec u|=1$ comes in?

Comment: The question might as well have been "Let $a,u$ be vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ where $|u|\ne 0$...

Comment: I think you're correct, @TonyK, but perhaps this question arose from a particular circumstance where $|u|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the distributive law, $(\vec a-t\vec u)\cdot \vec u=\vec a\cdot \vec u-t\vec u\cdot \vec u$,

so, if $\vec a-t\vec u$ is orthogonal to $\vec u$, we then have $\vec a\cdot \vec u-t\vec u\cdot \vec u=0.$

Can you then solve for $t$?

Note that $|\vec u|=1$ means that $\vec u\cdot \vec u=|\vec u|^2=1\ne0$,

so there is no problem dividing by $\vec u \cdot \vec u$.